# newview not invoke in ResourceCursorAdapter

Tags: android

I use  ResourceCursorAdapter , first screen show 4 item， I scroll to bottom ,the 5 and next repeat ,in fact the fifth item is show the first item, I found is directly invoke bindview  not newview,I don't know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the fifth item is actually a recycled first item. Android recycles its list items for better performance. newView only called when the adapter want to inflate new view from XML file. So there is no guarantee that for every list item the newView will be called.

Comment: yes,when I override next methods: public int getViewTypeCount() and public int getItemViewType(int position) the bug dismiss,in baseadapter ,I use tag solve this bug ,